# How to create a kinetic depth effect illusion?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create a 3D object with a texture of white dots on a black field (like stars). I also want the background to have the same texture such that, when static, the object appears invisible (the kinetic depth effect). How would you recommedn doing that?

Comment: Can you provide image samples of the effect? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest, something like this?

- Create an environment-sphere, and put the camera and target object inside it.

[image]

- Give the sphere your desired star-field texture in its object space, something like this:

[image]

- Give the target a *copy* of the material: you will change its texture-scale manually to match the background as closely as possible.
- Give the camera a reasonably long focal length. (Here, 100mm.) The more closely the camera approaches orthographic, and the more distant the target from the camera, the less apparent variation in texture-scale there will be between the near and far points of the target, but you sacrifice some perspectival visual cues.

For this sort of result:

[image]

I guess you could automate the scale of the texture according to the distance of the shading-point from the camera, but I'm not sure the resultant 'swimming' of the object through the texture would help.. I haven't tried it.